# how to add dynamic button to push notification alert box and redirect to the desired UIView in iphone?

Tags: iphone, cordova, uilocalnotification

I have a task to create application with push notification when the notification send at that time it redirect user to the different user page without login in the application.

I have to work with the local notification in which i have to create custom alertbox. in which i have to customize the button title and redirect it to the different pages without login view.

Is it possible to set the user custom uialertbox with custom name button. and it redirect to the uiview without loading first view for login.

Please help me. And provide some sample for it.if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILocalNotification` are handled by the system and are not `UIAlertViews`.

You can set the button title for pushnotiftcaion or `UILocalNotification` by setting the `alertAction` property.

The notification has a `userInfo` property which you can fill with a `NSDictionary`, then in your appdelegate you can check the `userInfo` when you app launches and navigate the user to the view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Your normal code here.

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Check for a UILocalNotification
    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]; 

    if (notification ) {
       // handle the notification
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Comment: i forget to say that my hole application is in . phone gap sdk so how can i call that particular view or div with userinfo.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. Since I have no experience with phonegap.